# update database if value === $_POST value if not value already exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well that's basically what I'm trying to do.

I have a form that saves into the database, now if the email in this case, already exist, it gives me the error message that " user already exist.

and since I am echoing out the values from the database into the form fields it gives me that " user already exist" error every time i push update.
If don't echo out the value, when I'm updating the form, it saves an empty email address, or  `filter_validate_Email` function tells me that the email is not valid.

I tried and succeed when fixed the problem with check boxes but that's kind of messy and ugly so I am trying  if else statement but with no luck.
Any tips on how to manage this ?

Ill send you some code.

```
if(email_exists($_POST['email'])===($_POST['email'])){

    } 

    if(email_exists($_POST['email'])){
        $errors[] = 'email already registered';
    }
```

With that statement i was thinking of, if the $_POST email is equal to $_POST email.
do nothing, but if the email exist from email_exist function. `error email already exist.`

```
    if(empty($errors)){ 
        set_profile_info($_POST['firstname'],
        $_POST['lastname'],
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['about']);
    }
}
```

email_exists query

```
function email_exists($email){
    global $db;
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?" );
    $st->bindParam(1, $email);
    $st->execute();

    if($st->rowCount() ==1){
        return true;
    }
    else{ 
       return false;
    }
}
```

There are probably millions of other ways, but i cant figure anything else.
thanks

Comment: Your email_exists -function returns boolean, yet you're testing it against a string if(email_exists($_POST['email'])===($_POST['email'])){ ?! That would evaluate to something like if(true) === 'mail@ex.com') which is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UNIQUE index on your "email" field

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD UNIQUE INDEX EMAIL_UNIQUE(email);
```

then when you try to add user with email it will give you error/exception depends on what sql engine you use.

I've noticed  you use globals it's bad habit. Better create Registry or Singleton to get database object.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/OOP-Pattern-Registry-Introduction-Registry-Pattern-P240.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

also you do one strange thing. Why you use "===" which means "EXACT" variable with same type and then you compare string with boolean it will always return false.

change

```
if(email_exists($_POST['email'])===($_POST['email'])){
```

to

```
if(email_exists($_POST['email'])==($_POST['email'])){
```

or

```
if(email_exists($_POST['email'])===((bool)$_POST['email'])){
```

change

```
if(email_exists($_POST['email'])===($_POST['email'])){

} 

if(email_exists($_POST['email'])){
    $errors[] = 'email already registered';
}
```

to

```
$emailExists = email_exists($_POST['email'])
if(emailExists == $_POST['email']){
  //doing your stuff when email exists
} 

if(emailExists){
    //doing other stuff when email exists
    $errors[] = 'email already registered';
}
```

When you change it function that calls database will be only called once.

Comment: @robert I still get email already registred if I update the form witout changen the email value.